# How can I set up Broadcom drivers on a new Arch Linux install on MacBook Pro?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, broadcom

I'm setting up Arch Linux on a MacBook Pro, currently using a phone with USB tethering for internet access. An obvious short-term goal is to install Broadcom drivers (either `b43-firmware` or `broadcom-wl-dkms`), both of which I can get via `yaourt`.

So far, when trying to set up an interface after installing `broadcom-wl-dkms`, I'm hitting a roadblock because `/proc/bcrm_monitor0` doesn't exist, and I can't write `echo 1` to it because I *can't* create this file, even as root (this includes via `touch` and moving other files with the appropriate name and contents there). I get `No such file or directory` whenever I try to create or populate it in any way.

`pacman -Q broadcom-wl-dkms` shows that the driver is correctly installed.

How can I get Wi-Fi up and running in my Arch install?

Comment: Can you load the `wl` without problem after installing the `broadcom-wl-dkms`?

Comment: @GAD3R trying to load `wl` did raise an error, but I can't remember which one it was, and I can't recreate it because, oddly enough, the original issue was fixed by installing and enabling GNOME (though I'm not sure how, and I'm still investigating that; I'll follow up with an answer if I figure it out).